# Heap Sort Complexity

Tags: algorithm, heap, asymptotic-complexity, heapsort

Below is the Pseudo Code of HEAPSORT on an array

```
HEAPSORT(A)
  BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)
  for i = A.length downto 2
     exchange A[1] with A[i]
     A.heapsize = A.heapsize - 1
     MAX-HEAPIFY(A,1)
```

It is clear to me that BUILD-MAX-HEAP has a complexity of O(n) and MAX-HEAPIFY has a complexity of O(h) where h is the height of the heap which has a max value of logn.

What I don't understand completely is why does HeapSort have a complexity of nlogn. I understand we have n iterations with each a MAX-HEAPIFY. But he MAX-HEAPIFY call gets a HEAP of diminishing size in each iteration. How can then each iteration have a complexity of O(lgn)? Is it tightly bound? Any where I can see the mathematical proof of the same?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691923/build-max-heap-running-time-for-array-sorted-in-decreasing-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

```
log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log n
= log (1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n)
= log n!
```

Now, by Stirling's approximation,

```
n! ≈ sqrt(2πn) * (n/e)n
```

So:

```
log n! ≈ n * (log n/e) = n * (log n - 1)  = n log n - n
```

which is O(n log n) because the `n log n` term dominates the `n` term (and the O(log n) term I left out because it is too hard to type withou MathJax).

Comment: Beautiful! Just one typo, I think it should be log(n/e)

Answer (score 3):

Big O notation notates an *upper* bound. As you've said:

> MAX-HEAPIFY has a complexity of O(h) where h is the height of the heap which has a max value of log n.

We don't care if the heap gets smaller. We know that *at worst*, the heap has height *log n*. We do this *n* times, hence *n log n*.

Comment: Below is the Pseudo Code for BUILD-MAX-HEAP

_BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)

  A.heapsize = A.length

  for i = A.length/2 downto 1
     MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)

In the above we do take into account the depth of the Heap to calculate the complexity which is O(n). Why would we not do in HEAPSORT?

Comment: @lalatnayak Because we've cheated and already know that we can do no better than O(n log n) for heapsort (hint: we need a lower bound). Because of that we do not try to improve our upper bound.

Comment: Thanks, I doubt if I could have figured it out without the hint :)